# Raspberry Debian run on boot fails but manuel run works perfectly

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, instapy

Run on boot fails but script works perfeclt well on manuel. SO THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE Im trying to automate an instapy script with raspberry but when i try the run on boot options all of them fail with the error code ;

```
  InstaPy Version: 0.6.9
  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
  Workspace in use: "/root/InstaPy"
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/VersusInstaBot.py", line 15, in <module>
split_db=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 322, in __init__
self.logger,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 125, in 
  set_selenium_local_session
  options=firefox_options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

It workes perfectly well on manual start but no matter what method i use to run on boot fails with this code. systemd, autostart, rc.local and even bash all of them fails with this line. So i believe its not about the script itself. Its about the way raspberry tries to run it on boot

I realized that InstaPy tries to set workspace as /root/InstaPy i dont know if that matters but i tried to force it to set workspace as default path still nothing changes

By the way about that split_db = False code, it doesnt matter whether i change it do True or False or completely remove the code